# (AngularJS) Calculate dynamically subtotals for each different Percentage

Tags: angularjs

I am new to AngularJS and would be very grateful for a tip. I have a table with a column amount, and two columns of percentages. In these two columns, the user can enter different percentages.

Now I want to sum ​​up the amounts with the same percentages first and then multiplied by the percentage. A Subtotal row should then be created dynamically for each percentage.

Can you give me a hint? Here is a fiddle, to demonstrate it: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/marmuel/3H63C/2/)

**HTML**

```
<table ng:controller="SubTotalCtrl">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th ng:repeat="(i,th) in head" ng:class="selectedCls(i)" ng:click="changeSorting(i)">{{th}}</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng:repeat="row in body.$orderBy(sort.column, sort.descending)">
            <td><input value = {{row.a}}></input></td>
            <td><input value = {{row.b}}></input></td>
            <td><input value = {{row.c}}></input></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td><textarea>Label Subtotal Percent 5</textarea></td>      
        <td>= (Sum of all Amounts with 5% *  5 %)</td>
         </tr><tr> 
         <td></td>
        <td><textarea>Label Subtotal Percent 10</textarea></td>      
        <td>= (Sum of all Amounts with 10% *  10 %)</td>
        </tr><tr> 
        <td></td>
        <td><textarea>Label Subtotal Percent 20</textarea></td>      
        <td>= (Sum of all Amounts with 20% * 20%)</td>
         </tr>        
</table>
```

**SCRIPT**

```
function SubTotalCtrl() {
    var scope = this;

    // data
    scope.head = {
        a: "Amount",
        b: "Percent",
        c: "Percent"
    };
    scope.body = [{
        a: "1000",
        b: "5",
        c: "10"
    }, {
        a: "2000",
        b: "0",
        c: "5"
    }, {
        a: "3000",
        b: "10",
        c: "20"
    }];
}
```

Comment: @ExpertSystem, thank you for your comment! fiddle did not save my update. I´ve updated the fiddle link above.

Comment: angular-0.10.5 ??? Seriously ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are quite a few issues with your code (that are outside of the scope of this answer).
Most notably, you were using one (actually two) ancient version of Angular.

Regarding the actual question (how to generate dynamically percentage-groups and total amount per group):

**1.**
You need a way to bind your view to your model. This means you need to show in the view whatever percentages are assigned per row **and** update yur model (your data) whenever the user enters a new value (e.g. modifies some percentage value).
Angular makes it super easy with its two-way data binding:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="row.a" />
// Now he input will show whatever value is stored in `$scope.row.a`
// and `$scope.row.a` will get automatically updated whenever the user
// enters a different value into the text-field.
```

**2.**
You need to create the percentage groups and use `ngRepeat` to render one row for each group. This needs to be dynamic, because the groups will change according to the user's input.
I find that the following format works nicely:

```
groups = {
    <percentage1>: <sumOfAmounts1>
    <percentage2>: <sumOfAmounts2>
    ...
```

E.g.

```
groups = {
    '5': 1200,
    '10': 700,
    ...
```

Then utilize it in your viewlike this:

```
<tr ng-repeat="(perc, sum) in grouppedByPercentage()">
    <td></td>
    <td>Subtotal for {{perc}}%</td>      
    <td>{{sum * perc / 100.0}}</td>
</tr>
```

**3.**
Finally, you need a method in your `$scope` that generates and returns the groups:

```
$scope.grouppedByPercentage = function () {
    var groups = {};
    $scope.body.forEach(function (row) {
        ['b', 'c'].forEach(function (key) {
            var perc = row[key];
            if (perc === '0') { return; }   // ignore 0 percentage

            if (!groups[perc]) {
                // The group for this percentage does not exist
                // Let's create it first
                groups[perc] = 0;
            }
            groups[perc] += parseInt(row.a);
            // use `parseFloat()` if you want decimal points
        });
    });
    return groups;
};
```

See, also, this **[short demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ExpertSystem/LD7QS/1/)**.

---

**NOTE:**
There are more efficient ways of doing this (e.g. generating the groups once and then watch for changes in the data before re-generating them), but I opted for keeping this as simple as possible, considering your "newbie" Angular status.

---

**UPDATE**

**[This is an extended version](http://jsfiddle.net/ExpertSystem/LD7QS/)** of the original demo, where besides the original (simpler approach), there is an alternative that is more efficient (computationally) and sorts percentages correctly.

Comparison between solutions:

**Solution 1** (uses an object):
**+** Probably easier to understand (more straight forward).
**-** Less efficient (generates the groups at every digest cycle (there can be many of those).
**-** Sorts percentages as strings (not as numbers), which results in e.g. `10%` appearing before `5%`.

**Solution 2** (uses an array):
**-** Slightly more complex (e.g. it uses a `$watch`).
**+** More efficient (generates  the groups only when the data actually changes).
**+** Sorts percentages as numbers, so everything appears in the correct (arithmetic) order.

Comment: NP :) Don't hesitate to come back for clarifications should something not make sense. There is quite a lot to learn with Angular, but once you get how everything works it offers so much power (is many different aspects: e.g. reduced code size, maintainability, testability, "declarativeness")

Comment: Thank you so much! I have no add a new fiddle to adapt your wonderful (performant) approach. But I get an 'undefined-exception' As you can see, I have updated my fiddle a lot, but with no success...[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/marmuel/66vPN/11/)

Comment: I am on mobile, so I can't take a deeper look, but you seem to have mixed the 2 methods. In the view, you should be using `group.perc` and `group.sum` (not just `perc` and `sum`).

Comment: What a Service! No Problem:-) I´ve added group.perc and group.sum. Now I don´t get any exception. But the subtotal-row shows 'Subtotal for undefined% null'

Comment: not working fiddle with the group.perc and group.sum in the view [the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/marmuel/66vPN/18/)

Comment: You need to ay some more attention and try to understand what you do. In your sample invoice there is no amount property. (Also, in Chrome there seems to be an issue with accessing localStorage from an iframe or something, so try to remove that part.)

Comment: Thanks for your hint. The Amount will be calculated and not set by the sample invoice. Actually, 'group-sum' is null. I will try to understand it, you are absolutely right!

Comment: Yes, group.sum is null because it is the result of summing invoice.amount (but invoice.amount is undefined).